# Convert String to Type unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

Given a string and a type of number, I would like to check if the string can be converted to that type and would like the string to be converted to that type if possible. Bellow is the sudo code for what I am trying to do:

```
public bool DataIsValid(string s, Type someNumType) {
    d = 0; // a class member double variable

    if (s.CanBeConvertedTo(someNumType)) {
        d = (double)s;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
}
```

I'm always trying to convert a string to some type of number but I don't know what type. I've tried using a try/catch block with

```
d = (double)Convert.ChangeType(s, someNumType);
```

but this only works for doubles. With integers I get the error "System.InvalidCastException".

I think the issue is with casting it back to a double after I have converted it (because it works with doubles and not ints). Might

```
object data = Convert.ChangeType(s, someNumType)
d = (double)data;
```

work?

Comment: you can try the trycast method which returns a boolen if it's successful or not in converting the type. if you trying to convert to a number then that's integer right? or you mean it could be double or float as well? What's the error message when you try to convert to an integer?

Comment: what is the Convert.ChangeType method? Did you try TryCast?

Comment: in your case, the string is always a numeric one? and what's the point of int or double? may you give us a real example please?

Comment: @Baahuali been looking for an example of how to use TryCast and can't find one.

Comment: @rm.szc81 the string is input by the user and I want to make sure it's the appropriate type (but I don't know what the type is at compile).

Comment: @Commonaught in this case, I'd always try to cast to double. is there any reason for using both types (double and int)?

Comment: @rm.szc81 I'm using this for the attributes of shapes. Side length etc. are all doubles but some are int (like number of sides of a polygon). About your earlier comment: the string won't necessarily be numeric because the user could input a random string of characters.

Comment: @Commonaught Could you add some code that calls `DataIsValid`, please?

Comment: What would be an example of a number that's convertible to an `int`, but not to a `double`? What about `short`, or `byte`, or `float` - aren't they all easily fitting into a `double`? Your question is unclear at best - what are you actually trying to do, and why is the exact data type so important?

Comment: @CoolBots one user input, number of sides of a polygon, only makes sense as an int, but yes, they all fit fine in a double.

Comment: After searching for the last few hours I've decided just to hard code in something to test if the value is an integer value in the appropriate situations. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted using the following:

```
public bool DataIsValid(string s, Type someType) {
    o = 0; // a class member object variable

    try { o = Convert.ChangeType(s, someType); }
    catch { return false; }

    return true;
}

//using the object variable
double someDouble = (double)0;
//some more code
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You try checking with the type in if/switch conditions using [typeof](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typeof-operator-keyword-in-c-sharp/) operator and return response accordingly like this:

```
public bool DataIsValid(string s, Type someNumType) {
d = 0; // a class member variable

   if(someNumType == typeof(int))
   {
     d = int.Parse(s);
     return true;
   }
   if(someNumType == typeof(double))
   {
     d = double.Parse(s);
     return true;
   }
   if(someNumType == typeof(decimal))
   {
     d = decimal.Parse(s);
     return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: it's a solution, I agree with this but, in his case, he said that the measures of sides are double and the side count is integer. in his case, I'd take everything as a double since, the math operations between the same type would avoid implicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you can use `ChangeType` by using a generic method with `IConvertible` constraint.

It will take two parameters:

- The string to convert,
- The data value to change as `out`.

So we use a simple `try - ChangeType - catch` to do the operation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a value from a string and return true if success
/// else return false if not convertible
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The generic type parameter</typeparam>
/// <param name="str">The string to convert</param>
/// <param name="value">The value to get</param>
/// <returns>The converted value if success else the default of the type</returns>
public bool GetValueFromString<T>(string str, out T value)
  where T : IConvertible
{
  try
  {
    value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
    value = default(T);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
void Test()
{
  int valueInt = 0;
  double valueDouble = 0;
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<int>(text) : " + GetValueFromString("text", out valueInt));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<int>(-4) : " + GetValueFromString("-4", out valueInt));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<int>(4) : " + GetValueFromString("4", out valueInt));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<int>(4,3) : " + GetValueFromString("4,3", out valueInt));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<double>(text) : " + GetValueFromString("text", out valueDouble));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<double>(-4) : " + GetValueFromString("-4", out valueDouble));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<double>(4) : " + GetValueFromString("4", out valueDouble));
  Console.WriteLine("DataIsValid<double>(4,3) : " + GetValueFromString("4,3", out valueDouble));
}
```

Output:

```
DataIsValid<int>(text) : False
DataIsValid<int>(-4) : True
DataIsValid<int>(4) : True
DataIsValid<int>(4,3) : False
DataIsValid<double>(text) : False
DataIsValid<double>(-4) : True
DataIsValid<double>(4) : True
DataIsValid<double>(4,3) : True
```